# Trying to use VBA variable in Access UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

So as the title says I am trying to use a VBA variable within an update statement. This is being used because I want to loop through each cell in a range and subtract a value from the worksheet from a value within the table corresponding to that iterations cell reference. However, statement runs an error saying "too many parentheses." However, this is odd to me b/c I pulled the SQL syntax directly out of access. I guess I am missing something? I will post both versions of the code:

Code with vba variables :

```
Private Sub UPDIZZLE()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim QUV As Long
    Dim IID As String

    Set rRng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:b100")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell <> "" And rCell.Value <> 0 Then
           IID = rCell
           QUV = rCell.Offset(0,x).Value
            strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb"
            con.Open strConnection
            rs.Open "UPDATE Stuff SET Stuff.Quantity = Quantity-" & QUV & " WHERE (((Stuff.[ItemID])=" & IID & "));", con
            con.Close
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

code without variable:

```
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ashleysaurus\Desktop" & "\" & "xyzmanu3.accdb"
    con.Open strConnection
    rs.Open "UPDATE Stuff SET Stuff.Quantity = Quantity-1 WHERE (((Stuff.[ItemID])=Thingamagig));", con
    con.Close
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `IID` value itself contains a parenthese?

Comment: As `IID` is a string shouldn't it be `rs.Open "UPDATE Stuff SET Stuff.Quantity = Quantity-" & QUV & " WHERE (((Stuff.[ItemID])='" & IID & "'));", con` (single quotes around `IID`).

Comment: you know I couldve made a pretty dumb noob mistake, ill try it and post back

Comment: Don't use an ADODB.Recordset object to do an UPDATE; use an ADODB.Command object instead. Then you can use a *parameterized query* to specify the values to be included in the update.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, if youd want feedback for a correct answer please pst as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `IID` is a string shouldn't it be

```
    rs.Open "UPDATE Stuff SET Stuff.Quantity = Quantity-" & QUV & " WHERE (((Stuff.[ItemID])='" & IID & "'));", con
```

(single quotes around IID)